# Run menu is not coming inside perspective.

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have created one perspective named as "my perspective".When i run it as "Run as eclipse application",It show all sub menu inside "Run" menu but when i create plugin out of it,it shows me only "external tool" option inside "Run" menu.What is the reason & how can i resolve it?

Comment: what's your programming language?

Comment: I am using java & creating perspective in Eclipse.

Comment: Are to contributing to exiting 'Run' menu or creating your own 'Run' menu?

Comment: I am contribute in existing 'Run' menu.

Comment: and its a plug-in for Eclipse (IDE/SDK) and NOT an RCP application?

Comment: Yes,Its not for RCP,Its for IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Most of Run menu items are contributed from `org.eclipse.debug.ui`. You need to include that plugin into launch configuration in order to get Run menu items populated.
The simplest way is to add dependency on `org.eclipse.debug.ui` into your plugin.

Cheers,
Max

Comment: I have  added this dependency but still its not showing.Is perspective depends on that what views you are showing in your custom perspective.